# What's the status of the proposed NaNoWriMo promotion?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, nanowrimo

There was some discussion (primarily involving @HedgeMage and the CHAOS team) of a NaNoWriMo promotion for Writers.SE. We're on the cusp of the event, and I haven't seen any actual announcements.

Is the promotion going forward? What should we be expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HedgeMage](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/111/hedgemage), [Aarthi](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/2580/aarthi-devanathan), and [Sam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166581/samthebrand) have been working on some promotional activities for the National Novel Writing Month (NaNoWriMo), but with time running short, we have not been able to get enough information from the national group to put together anything substantial. At this late date, I think we are going to have to shelve our NaNoWriMo plans for this event and focus on some related activities.

The NaNoWriMo event is still a good opportunity for Writers SE so, hopefully, we can establish a significant presence for the next one. In the meantime, with the time and effort we put into this, we are going to pursue some activities with the some of the local groups and maybe make some inroads with other writing organizations.

As always, your suggestions and feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything I can do to help, I'm doing Nano and odds are I'm in a different local group than others so I'm happy to try and drum up some interest

Comment: There were some suggestions in the [chat discussions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2119391#2119391) about at least showing some presence in the forums. Anything with that?

Comment: I mentioned it in the useful websites section